# Injecting html snippet with JQuery into existing html page

Tags: jquery

I want to inject certain html snippet with JQuery into existing html page.
Existing snippet:

```
<table class="course hoverHighlight">
    <tbody>...</tbody>
       ...
</table>
```

I want to inject:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="title">Course</th>
            <th class="author">Author</th>
            <th class="level">Level</th>
            <th class="rating">Rating</th>
            <th class="duration">Duration</th>
            <th class="releaseDate">Released</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
```

before *tbody* tag.

```
<table class="course hoverHighlight">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>

</table>
```

I have tried this code but it didn`t work:

```
function() {
    var theadInjection= $("<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="title">course</th>
        <th class="author">author</th>
        <th class="level">level</th>
        <th class="rating">rating</th>
        <th class="duration">duration</th>
        <th class="releasedate">released</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>");
   $( '.course' ).prepend(theadInjection);
```

}

Simple injection like this one did work:

```
function() {
    var theadInjection= $("<thead></thead>");
   $( '.course' ).prepend(theadInjection);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error? take a look at your quotes and you need to escape the new line

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/nnV67/

Comment: Yes there is an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 0):

You should be seeing a syntax error.  This would work if you properly escaped your quotes and newline.  In this case you can simply use single quotes:

```
  var theadInjection= $("<thead> \
    <tr> \
        <th class='title'>course</th> \ 
      //more headers here
    </tr> \
    </thead>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `"` around your class attributes are ending your string. You'll need to change them to `'` or switch to `'` around the whole string. However you also have a second problem. Javascript doesn't do multiline strings without some extra work. [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

```
 var theadInjection= $('<thead> \
    <tr> \
        <th class="title">course</th> \
        <th class="author">author</th> \
        <th class="level">level</th> \
        <th class="rating">rating</th> \
        <th class="duration">duration</th> \
        <th class="releasedate">released</th> \
    </tr> \
    </thead>');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this approach too.